# onMouseEnter is not working for a div in next app while the div is passed down as children

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, next.js

I have a map app that renders markers on Google Maps. The marker is passed down to the component as a div to render there.

The solution is from the official youtube channel for Map Developers. The dive passed down to MyMarker is the one rendered as a marker, and I need to use onClick and onMouse enter for that div.

Here is the code sandbox link, I have created it with Next 13, but in sandbox, Next is an earlier version, Please keep in mind: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/frosty-moore-2kmtio
Please obtain a google map API key and create a MapId, past it where it mentioned

```
const Properties = ({ data, map }) => {
    const [highlited, sethighlited] = useState(null)
    function handleMouseEnter() {
        console.log('Mouse entered');
    }
    return (
        <>
            {
                data.map((e, i) => {
                    
                   return (<MyMarker key={i} map={map} data={e} position={{
                    lat: e.location.coords.latitude,
                    lng: e.location.coords.longitude,
                }}>
                    <div
                    
                        className={` bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-full`}
                        onMouseEnter={() => console.log("Mouse enter")}>
                           <h2>{`${e.price}`}</h2>
                    </div>
                </MyMarker>)})
            }

        </>
    )
}
========The marker====
const MyMarker = ({ data, map, children, position }) => {
    const rootRef = useRef()
    const markerRef = useRef()

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!rootRef.current) {
            const container = document.createElement("div");
            rootRef.current = createRoot(container)
            markerRef.current = new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerView({
                position: position,
                content: container
            })

        }

    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        rootRef.current.render(children)
        markerRef.current.position = position
        markerRef.current.map = map

    }, [position, map, children])


}
```

Here the onMouseEnter is not working

I have tried rendering it directly, but it won't work

Comment: What library are you using? Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example]() that reproduces the issue. A working [codesandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be good so that the community would be able to check try to debug.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/frosty-moore-2kmtio . Thank you, Like you said, Here is the code sandbox, Please check